# Using Haml Helpers That Return Strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I love using Haml helpers, but over the years things have changed a bit. The old way was simply to concatenate to the buffer. Here's what I have:

```
def confirmation_table(field)
  # Be certain that if the user is logged in, his/her email and name show
  if field.respond_to? :user
    haml_tag('tr') {
      haml_tag('th', 'Email:')
      haml_tag('td', field.user.email)
    }
    haml_tag('tr') {      
      haml_tag('th', 'Name:')
      haml_tag('td', field.user.full_name)
    }
  else
    haml_tag('tr') {
      haml_tag('th', 'User Information:')
      haml_tag('td', 'Not specified.')
    }
  end

  field.class.columns.collect{|col| col.name}.reject{|col| 
    col =~ /_at$/ || 
    col =~ /_on$/ ||
    col =~ /_id$/ ||
    col == 'id'}.each do |col|
    haml_tag('tr') {
      haml_tag('th', ActiveSupport::Inflector::humanize(col))
      haml_tag('td', typeize(field, col))
    }
  end
end
```

This can, of course, be accessed in my view as simply as:

```
- confirmation_table(@f)
```

However, it makes more sense (to me) for this to return a string. I can't see how `haml_capture` provides the same structuring ability. Any hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap your `haml_tag` calls in `capture_haml`:

```
def confirmation_table(field)
  capture_haml do
    if field.respond_to? :user
      haml_tag(:tr) do
        haml_tag('th.email', 'Email:')
        haml_tag('td.email', field.user.email)
      end
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

They'll be captured and returned by `capture_haml`.

Comment: Would you please complete your example so that it is standalone and minimally viable?

Comment: What do you mean? Adding some `haml_tag` calls ? Or a sample usage of this helper in a HAML view?

Comment: Yes, adding more than one `haml_tag` calls. I know it sounds dumb, but I am trying to use `haml` from command line without having RoR installed and I am seeing some problems that most folks do not. Therefore, I would like a full (but small) example.

Comment: I added a few examples from the original question but you should ask a new question if you want solutions to your problems.